# Working with aws_lambda_permission and aws_apigatewayv2_api

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to work with aws_apigatewayv2_api and aws_lambda_permission resources, but the examples I've found online show something like this (I omitted the resources which are not important for this specific issue):

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "users_api" {
  name          = "API"
  description   = "Users API"
  protocol_type = "HTTP"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_stage" "api_stage" {
  api_id      = aws_apigatewayv2_api.users_api.id
  name        = "$default"
  auto_deploy = true
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_integration" "get_user_integration" {
  api_id           = aws_apigatewayv2_api.users_api.id
  integration_type = "AWS_PROXY"

  connection_type    = "INTERNET"
  description        = "Get User"
  integration_method = "POST"
  integration_uri    = aws_lambda_function.get_user_lambda.invoke_arn

  payload_format_version = "2.0"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "get_user_route" {
  api_id    = aws_apigatewayv2_api.users_api.id
  route_key = "GET /users"
  target    = "integrations/${aws_apigatewayv2_integration.get_user_integration.id}"
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "api_permission" {
  statement_id  = "allow_apigw_invoke"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.get_user_lambda.function_name
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "${aws_apigatewayv2_stage.api_stage.execution_arn}/${aws_apigatewayv2_route.api_route.route_key}"
```

The problem seems to come from `source_arn`, because after creating the resources, I'm getting the following error on the API Gateway trigger:
`the API with ID *id* doesn’t include a route with path /users`.

I've managed to work around this by doing the following:

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "api_permission" {
  statement_id  = "allow_apigw_invoke"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.get_user_lambda.function_name
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.users_api.execution_arn}/*/*/${split("/", aws_apigatewayv2_route.get_user_route.route_key)[1]}"
}
```

But this just seems a bit counterintuitive and...wrong?
Am I missing something, is there a more straightforward way to accomplish this?

Comment: From the example you posted, the wrong `aws_apigatewayv2_route` is referenced, i.e., the route that is created is `aws_apigatewayv2_route.api_route.route_key` but you are trying to reference the one that does not exist. But my guess is that it's not the underlying issue. :)

Comment: Also, it would be valuable to have the `aws_apigatewayv2_integration` code as as well. :)

Comment: And IIRC my issues with API Gateway, the method has to be `POST` when using Lambda for integration: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-integrations.html.

Comment: I added the code for the `aws_apigatewayv2_integration`. The method for the integration is POST, but the method for the API route is GET.

Comment: So, the `source_arn` is most surely not going to work the first way. It has to have the following structure: `arn:aws:execute-api:region:account-id:api-id/stage-name/HTTP-VERB/resource-path-specifier`. So is should be something like `"${aws_apigatewayv2_stage.api_stage.execution_arn}/*/GET/${aws_apigatewayv2_route.api_route.route_key}"`. I think. But you might as well create an output for the API Gateway execution ARN and check if it looks like what you expect.

Comment: Also, this is from the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#:~:text=You%20can%20set,placeholder%2C%20or%20both..