# What will be the purpose of .function_name in terraform code

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm learning more about terraform and AWS. I've seen a code in
[Working with aws_lambda_permission and aws_apigatewayv2_api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70814499/working-with-aws-lambda-permission-and-aws-apigatewayv2-api/73890242#73890242)

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "api_permission" {
  statement_id  = "allow_apigw_invoke"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.get_user_lambda.lambda_function_name
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.users_api.execution_arn}/*/*/${split("/", aws_apigatewayv2_route.get_user_route.route_key)[1]}"
```

}

I would like to know why the function name is given as

**function_name = aws_lambda_function.get_user_lambda.lambda_function_name**

***Is there any single term used to indicate module.name of the module.function name***

Comment: Where is the module you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to change your function name when you define `aws_lambda_function.get_user_lambda`, you will have to manually updated entire codebase to change the name in other parts which depend on the function.

Using `aws_lambda_function.get_user_lambda.function_name` saves you a lot of work, as correct name will be used always, and you do not have to manually change that name.

Comment: In which situation we can replace .lambda_function_name into just .name

Comment: @AnandSukumaran You can replace it anytime you want. It's entirely your design choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
  filename      = "lambdatest.zip"
  function_name = var.lambda_function_name
  role          = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn
  handler       = "exports.handler"
  runtime       = "nodejs12.x"
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_cloudwatch" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromCloudWatch"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.test_lambda.function_name
  principal     = "events.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "arn:aws:events:eu-west-1:111122223333:rule/RunDaily"
  qualifier     = aws_lambda_alias.test_alias.name
}
```

Defining aws_lambda_function.test_lambda.function_name instead of direct function name gives us an advantage of configurable property at run time.

..........

Answer (score 0):

You've got two related resources; a `aws_lambda_permission` resource, and a `aws_lambda_function`. `function_name` is one of the required parameters for `aws_lambda_permission`; it tells Terraform *which* Lambda function to apply the permission to.

You can certainly hard-code a function name, if you want, but doing it this way means changing the `aws_lambda_function`'s name doesn't require you to also change the hard-coded name in the associated `aws_lambda_permission`. Terraform may also not understand the dependencies between the function and its permission this way and wind up creating things out-of-order.

Comment: Mentioning `aws_lambda_function.get_user_lambda` in the configuration of `resource "aws_lambda_permission" "api_permission"` is also telling Terraform that any Lambda function actions must happen before any Lambda permission actions during the plan and apply process, so replacing that reference with a literal function name would mean a missing dependency that would probably cause intermittent errors.

Comment: Great point, @MartinAtkins. I'll add that to the answer.